# How to position a button consistently within a group of similar divs in a row?

Tags: html, css, web-frontend

The issue I'm encountering pertains to the consistent positioning of a button within a collection of similar  elements in a row. Here's a breakdown of the problem:

1. HTML Structure:
   I have a row containing several  elements, each of which contains its unique content. This content comprises an SVG icon, a title, a description, and a "VIEW DETAILS" button.
2. Button Overflow:
   The challenge I'm facing is that the "VIEW DETAILS" button sometimes overflows its parent , disrupting the intended layout.
3. Desired Outcome:
   My objective is to have the "VIEW DETAILS" button consistently positioned within each . I want to ensure that the button's placement remains identical for every  within the row, irrespective of the content inside each .

`

```
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 d-flex align-items-stretch" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
        <div class="icon-box iconbox-blue">
          <div class="icon">
            <svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
              <path stroke="none" stroke-width="0" fill="#f5f5f5"
                d="M300,521.0016835830174C376.1290562159157,517.8887921683347,466.0731472004068,529.7835943286574,510.70327084640275,468.03025145048787C554.3714126377745,407.6079735673963,508.03601936045806,328.9844924480964,491.2728898941984,256.3432110539036C474.5976632858925,184.082847569629,479.9380746630129,96.60480741107993,416.23090153303,58.64404602377083C348.86323505073057,18.502131276798302,261.93793281208167,40.57373210992963,193.5410806939664,78.93577620505333C130.42746243093433,114.334589627462,98.30271207620316,179.96522072025542,76.75703585869454,249.04625023123273C51.97151888228291,328.5150500222984,13.704378332031375,421.85034740162234,66.52175969318436,486.19268352777647C119.04800174914682,550.1803526380478,217.28368757567262,524.383925680826,300,521.0016835830174">
              </path>
            </svg>
            <i class="bx bx-check-shield"></i>
          </div>
          <h4><a href="">Test Text Heading</a></h4>
          <p>test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text test text </p>
          <a href="#"><button class="button-33" style="margin-top: 40px; width: 100%;">VIEW DETAILS</button></a>
        </div>
      </div>
```

`

What I've Tried:

I have attempted several solutions to address the issue, but none of them have provided the desired result. Specifically, I have tried:

Using CSS positioning properties (position: absolute, bottom, right) to control the button's placement within each <div>.
Adjusting the width, height, and max-width properties of the parent container (.icon-box) and the button to ensure proper sizing and containment.
Inspecting the elements using browser developer tools to identify any conflicting styles or unexpected margin/padding.
Despite these efforts, the button still overflows the parent <div> in some instances, which is not the intended behavior.

Expectations:

I expected that by using the CSS positioning properties and adjusting the sizes and properties of the button and container, I would be able to consistently position the "VIEW DETAILS" button within each <div> without it overflowing. The desired outcome is to ensure that the button's position remains the same for every <div> within the row, regardless of the content within the <div>.

I'm looking for guidance on the correct CSS adjustments or potential issues that might be causing this behavior. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few missing infos to be able to answer your question with complete certainty, but based on the following assumptions:

- You want to place the button consistently in divs whose content may vary in length
- the classes attached to your elements are self-explanatory based on their names

Here's how I would proceed:

**CSS**

```css
.row-element {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.card-item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;
}
.card-item__button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<div class="row-element">

  <div class="card-item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="icon-box iconbox-blue">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">{…}
        </svg>
        <i class="bx bx-check-shield"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#"><h4>Test Text Heading</h4></a>
    <p>I'm a card with a super long description. A communi observantia non est recedendum. Quisque ut dolor gravida, placerat libero vel, euismod. Fictum, deserunt mollit anim laborum astutumque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-item__button">VIEW DETAILS</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card-item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="icon-box iconbox-blue">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg width="100" height="100" viewbox="0 0 600 600" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">{…}
        </svg>
        <i class="bx bx-check-shield"></i>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#"><h4>Test Text Heading</h4></a>
    <p>I'm a card with a short description.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-item__button">VIEW DETAILS</a>
  </div>

  {sibling card items here}

</div>
```

The way it works is the following:

- the div with `class="row-element"` is a flex container that forces its children to grow in height to match the tallest one among them (`align-items: stretch`)
- the divs with the `class="card-item"` are children of that `row-element` parent. They also are flex containers, with a flex direction of column. Their children will be placed at the top (`justify-content: flex-start`) , but the button has a `margin-top: auto` declaration, which will push it to the bottom of the card, achieving the desired effect.

Here's a demonstration of it working (Click “Run code snippet” to see the result):

```css
html {
  font-family: "Inter", Helvetica Neue, Helvetica;
}

.row-element {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: stretch;
  gap: 1.5rem;
  max-width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.card-item {
  flex: 1 1 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: stretch;

  border: solid 2px hsl(180deg, 10%, 85%);
  border-radius: 2.25rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
}

.icon {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: .75rem;
  border-radius: 999px;
  color: hsl(180deg, 80%, 66%);
  background: hsl(180deg, 20%, 10%);
}
.icon svg {
  display: block;
}

.card-item h4 {
  font-size: 2rem;
  margin: .75rem 0 0;
}
.card-item p {
  margin: 1.5rem 0 1.5rem;
}
.card-item a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.card-item__button {
  margin-top: auto;
  align-self: flex-start;
  padding: .75rem 1.5rem;
  border-radius: .75rem;
  font-weight: 600;
  background-color: hsl(180deg, 20%, 90%);
  transition: transform .25s;
}
.card-item__button:hover {
  transform: scale(1.05);
}
```

```html
<div class="row-element">

  <div class="card-item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="icon-box iconbox-blue">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M9.75 3.104v5.714a2.25 2.25 0 01-.659 1.591L5 14.5M9.75 3.104c-.251.023-.501.05-.75.082m.75-.082a24.301 24.301 0 014.5 0m0 0v5.714c0 .597.237 1.17.659 1.591L19.8 15.3M14.25 3.104c.251.023.501.05.75.082M19.8 15.3l-1.57.393A9.065 9.065 0 0112 15a9.065 9.065 0 00-6.23-.693L5 14.5m14.8.8l1.402 1.402c1.232 1.232.65 3.318-1.067 3.611A48.309 48.309 0 0112 21c-2.773 0-5.491-.235-8.135-.687-1.718-.293-2.3-2.379-1.067-3.61L5 14.5" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <h4><a href="#">Test Text Heading</a></h4>
    <p>I'm a card with a super long description. A communi observantia non est recedendum. Quisque ut dolor gravida, placerat libero vel, euismod. Fictum, deserunt mollit anim laborum astutumque! Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisici elit, sed eiusmod tempor incidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-item__button">VIEW DETAILS</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card-item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="icon-box iconbox-blue">
      <div class="icon">
        
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M14.857 17.082a23.848 23.848 0 005.454-1.31A8.967 8.967 0 0118 9.75v-.7V9A6 6 0 006 9v.75a8.967 8.967 0 01-2.312 6.022c1.733.64 3.56 1.085 5.455 1.31m5.714 0a24.255 24.255 0 01-5.714 0m5.714 0a3 3 0 11-5.714 0" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#"><h4>Test Text Heading</h4></a>
    <p>I'm a card with a short description.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-item__button">VIEW DETAILS</a>
  </div>

  <div class="card-item col-lg-4 col-md-6">
    <div class="icon-box iconbox-blue">
      <div class="icon">
        <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" width="24" height="24" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke-width="1.5" stroke="currentColor" class="w-6 h-6">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" d="M12 9.75v6.75m0 0l-3-3m3 3l3-3m-8.25 6a4.5 4.5 0 01-1.41-8.775 5.25 5.25 0 0110.233-2.33 3 3 0 013.758 3.848A3.752 3.752 0 0118 19.5H6.75z" />
        </svg>
      </div>
    </div>
    <a href="#"><h4>Test Text Heading</h4></a>
    <p>I'm a card with a short description.</p>
    <a href="#" class="card-item__button">VIEW DETAILS</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

**Note:**

You can't use a `button` inside an `<a>` element. Choose one of the two (if it's a link to another page, keep the `<a>`. if it's an action on the same page, keep the `<button>`)